# how I validate JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, dom, event-handling

Here when multiplying -1 to any variable it turns to negative. It uses for when the balance is withdrawn balance decreases but I set if the condition for validation for this reason -1 does not work. how I validate properly and balance also decreases when

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bank || Project</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- css link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="login-area" class="login-area">
    <h1 class="bank-title">Welcome To Pioneer Bank</h1>
    <div class="submit-area">
      <h4>Login</h4>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email...">
      <br>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password...">
      <br>
      <button type="submit" id="login-btn" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div id="transaction-area">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class=" deposit status">
          <h5>Deposit</h5>
          <h2>$ <span id="current-deposit">00</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 my-2 my-md-0">
        <div class=" withdraw status">
          <h5>Withdraw</h5>
          <h2>$ <span id="current-withdraw">00</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class=" balance status">
          <h5>Balance</h5>
          <h2>$ <span id="current-balance">1240</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="submit-area">
          <h4>Deposit</h4>
          <input type="text" id="deposit-amount" class="form-control" placeholder="$ amount you want to deposit">
          <br>
          <button id="deposit-btn" class="btn btn-success">Deposit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="submit-area">
          <h4>Withdraw</h4>
          <input type="text" id="withdraw-amount" class="form-control" placeholder="$ amount you want to withdraw">
          <br>
          <button id="withdraw-btn" class="btn btn-success">Withdraw</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    Here when multiplying -1 to any variable it turns to negative. It uses for when the balance is 
   withdrawn balance decreases but I set if the condition for validation for this reason -1 does not  
ork. how I validate properly and balance also decreases when

  // LOGIN BUTTON EVENT HANDLER
    const loginBtn = document.getElementById('login-btn');
    loginBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      const loginArea = document.getElementById('login-area');
      loginArea.style.display = 'none';

      const transactionArea = document.getElementById('transaction-area');
      transactionArea.style.display = 'block';
    })
    
    //deposit handler
    
    const depositBtn = document.getElementById('deposit-btn');
      depositBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
       
        const depositNumber = getInputNumber("deposit-amount");
   
  
        updateSpanText("current-deposit", depositNumber)
        updateSpanText("current-balance", depositNumber); 

      })
      
      
      
    // withdraw button handler
      const withdrawBtn = document.getElementById("withdraw-btn");
      withdrawBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

         const withdrawNumber =  getInputNumber("withdraw-amount"); 
          updateSpanText("current-withdraw", withdrawNumber);
          updateSpanText("current-balance",  withdrawNumber;

      })
      
      function getInputNumber(id) {
        const amount = document.getElementById(id).value;
        const amountNumber = parseFloat(amount);
        document.getElementById(id).value = "";
        return amountNumber;
      }

      Here when multiplying -1 to any variable it turns to negative. It uses for when the balance 
     is withdrawn balance decreases but I set if the condition for validation for this reason -1 does 
      not work. how I validate properly and balance also decreases when

      function updateSpanText(id, depositNumber) {
        if (depositNumber >= 0 && depositNumber !== '') { //here I set if condtition
          var currentBalance = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
        const currentBalanceNumber = parseFloat(currentBalance);
        const totalBalance = depositNumber + currentBalanceNumber;
        document.getElementById(id).innerText = totalBalance;
        } else {
          console.log(alert('Invalid input value'));
        }
  
  </script>
```

withdraw.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
// LOGIN BUTTON EVENT HANDLER
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('login-btn');
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const loginArea = document.getElementById('login-area');
    loginArea.style.display = 'none';

    const transactionArea = document.getElementById('transaction-area');
    transactionArea.style.display = 'block';
})

//deposit handler

const depositBtn = document.getElementById('deposit-btn');
depositBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

    const depositNumber = getInputNumber("deposit-amount");


    updateSpanText("current-deposit", depositNumber)
    updateSpanText("current-balance", depositNumber);

})



// withdraw button handler
const withdrawBtn = document.getElementById("withdraw-btn");
withdrawBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {

    const withdrawNumber = getInputNumber("withdraw-amount");
    updateSpanText("current-withdraw", withdrawNumber);
    updateSpanText("current-balance", withdrawNumber, true);

})

function getInputNumber(id) {
    const amount = document.getElementById(id).value;
    const amountNumber = parseFloat(amount);
    document.getElementById(id).value = "";
    return amountNumber;
}

function updateSpanText(id, depositNumber, isWithdraw = false) {
    if (depositNumber >= 0 && depositNumber !== '') { //here I set if condtition
        var currentBalance = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
        const currentBalanceNumber = parseFloat(currentBalance);
        const totalBalance = currentBalanceNumber + (isWithdraw ? -depositNumber : depositNumber);
        document.getElementById(id).innerText = totalBalance;
    } else {
        console.log(alert('Invalid input value'));
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bank || Project</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="login-area" class="login-area">
        <h1 class="bank-title">Welcome To Pioneer Bank</h1>
        <div class="submit-area">
            <h4>Login</h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email...">
            <br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password...">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" id="login-btn" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div id="transaction-area">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class=" deposit status">
                    <h5>Deposit</h5>
                    <h2>$ <span id="current-deposit">00</span></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 my-2 my-md-0">
                <div class=" withdraw status">
                    <h5>Withdraw</h5>
                    <h2>$ <span id="current-withdraw">00</span></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class=" balance status">
                    <h5>Balance</h5>
                    <h2>$ <span id="current-balance">1240</span></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="submit-area">
                    <h4>Deposit</h4>
                    <input type="text" id="deposit-amount" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="$ amount you want to deposit">
                    <br>
                    <button id="deposit-btn" class="btn btn-success">Deposit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="submit-area">
                    <h4>Withdraw</h4>
                    <input type="text" id="withdraw-amount" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="$ amount you want to withdraw">
                    <br>
                    <button id="withdraw-btn" class="btn btn-success">Withdraw</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```